# Let $a,b,c$ be three roots of equation $e^{2x}\sin(2x) - 7 = 0$. Then root of equation $e^{2x}\sin(2x) + 7 = 0$

Tags: calculus

Let $a,b,c$ be  three roots of equation $e^{2x}\sin(2x) - 7 = 0$. Then root of equation $e^{2x}\sin(2x) + 7 = 0$ lies between $C_1$ and $C_2$, where

- A. both $C_1$ and $C_2$ $\in (a,b)$
- B. Both $C_1$ and $C_2$ $\in (b,c)$
- C. $C_1$ $\in (a,b)$ and  $C_2$ $ \in (b,c)$
- D. $C_1$ $\in (a,b)$ and $C_2$ $\not\in (b,c)$

How do I start? Thanks

Comment: Is the answer a

Comment: @ArchisWelankar i do not know. Why?

Comment: Related, but not identical: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578696/alternating-roots-of-fx-expx-sinx-1-and-expx-cosx-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sin(2x)-7e^{-2x}$. Then between the three roots of $f$ there are by Rolle two roots of $f'$, and between them, again by Rolle, one root of 
$$
f''(x)=-4(\sin(2x)+7e^{-2x}).
$$
The use of Rolle's theorem gives you the structure of option (c).

Comment: Can  you add more details

Comment: Can you specify? $f$ and $f''$ have the same roots as the given functions, $C_1,C_2$ are the roots of $f'$.

Comment: How did you know how to write function f in that way to solve it ?

Comment: Because I've seen it before, and because it is a standard trick to either concentrate all the nastiness in one place or to separate it maximally. Since exponential terms are always positive, it is easy to shift them around.